# Socket client android doesn't show recieved message

Tags: java, android, sockets, server, client

i have a problem on my code 
i've created an app that send and recieve a message to/from server by clicking a

button

sending a message work very good 
but when recieving it doesn't show me anything
i want the app to show me message during the communication with the server sending and recieving and showing messages because i just noticed that during the communication the app can't display anything (toast or changing text of TextView/EditText or anything) expect just recieving data on variables without display
but i need the app to do a lot of things during the communication with server (showing toast and opening dialog boxes etc..)

the code onclick :

```
EditText nom ; //nom= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user); is in Oncreate methode

String name,check;
String check;
 public void click(View view) {


    name=nom.getText().toString();



    Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Socket s;


            try {

                s = new Socket(ipadresse,Integer.parseInt(por)); 
//those 2 (ip,por) are in methode (oncreate)

                DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());



                //emission just du nom (un exemple)
                dos.writeUTF(String.valueOf(name));
                //sending message

                //recieving a message :



                DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                check=dis.readUTF();


                //i've tried this command but not work :/ 
                //BufferedReader read=new BufferedReader(
                //new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

                //check= read.readLine();

                Log.i("message", "message recieved : "+check);

//logcat show me that the message recieved but toast doesn't 
//( in fact i didn't want toast i want to show a dialog box 
//but as a simple example i used toast)

                Toast.makeText(login.this, check, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                dos.flush();

                //dis.close();
                dos.close();
                s.close();



            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });


    t.start();




}
```

and here the sever code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread t;


        t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           try {
                    ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(8080);
                    System.out.println("connecting  ... ");
                    System.out.println("-------------------");


                        while(true) 
                        {
                            Socket s1= s.accept(); 

                           DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(s1.getInputStream());

                           DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(s1.getOutputStream());


                            String message;





                              message=dis.readUTF();

                           System.out.println(message);   


                           //this message does't displayed in the app (i've edited the program just to simplify it)    
                           dos.writeUTF("hello");



                            dis.close();
                            s1.close();
                        }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        });
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: where did you tell client to keep listening to the socket ?

Comment: i just used DataInputStream to receive message as i used DataOutputStream to send it

Comment: The Toast() will let your client app crash isnt it? You cannot use a Toast in the run() of a runnable().

Comment: i can't use toast nor edit a textview's text

Comment: i need to show the message and do other things without stopping communication ( just like chat or something )

Comment: The Toast() will let your app crash isnt it? Otherwise tell why you cannot use it to begin with!

Comment: `but i need the app to do a lot of things during the communication with server`. Hard to believe as you both close server and client after one message sent and received.

Comment: in fact i want when i recieve a certain message or exemple if (message.isequal("1"){ // i want to open a dialog box } but for now i used just Toast as an example , did you see what i mean ?

Comment: `The toast will let your app crash isnt it?`

Comment: yes it crash my app

Comment: You know why that happens?

Comment: but the point is not Toast , the point is i need to use the recieved message without stoping communication

Comment: Ok. Nice. But tell why your app crashes using a toast.

Comment: that's why i post the question

Comment: You have not posted any question. And you did not tell that your app crashed. I had to suggest and ask that three times.

Comment: ok , the app crashed  and when i used 
BufferedReader read=new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

check= read.readLine();
in place of 
  DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                check=dis.readUTF();


it didn't crash but it didn't show me the Toast

Comment: No it did not crash then. It hang.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: It hang in read.readLine(). That statement never finished. So the toast was never called. So your app did not crash. It hang.

Comment: even if i add read.close(); 
in the end of the socket ?

Comment: That statement will also never be executed.

Comment: Now it is really time you answer the simple question why a toast cannot be displayed there.

Comment: omg 
i don't know why it crash 
but logcat show me that my message has recieved

Comment: The logcat also tells you why it crashes.

Comment: no , i used logcat to see if my message even recieved or not

Comment: have an idea ???

Answer (score -1):

Maybe message from your server returns with delay(not in realtime). 
Try make loop:

```
boolean getmessage = false;
    while(!getmessage){
        try{
            check=dis.readUTF();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("dis", e.getMessage());
        }
        if(check != null){
            getmessage = true;
            makeToast("23");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If so it would block in `readUTF()` or throw a `SockerTimeoutException`if a read timeout had been set, which isn't mentioned.

Comment: So you can post full ready to use answer with Exceptions and throws =)

Comment: how ???
i want to show the message when it received without stopping communication (thread) and closing socket

Comment: @K.Vladislav Your remark is founded on a fallacy. It isn't necessary to be able to lay an egg to spot a rotten one.